# How to get JsonArray from PhP server android app?

Tags: php, android, json, arraylist, android-volley

Hi I have php code to encode an array and I want my android app to receive the array and store to the local variable

php code on server side:

```
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
```

how to make android to receive the array from server. I'm thinking of using Volley libray but dont know how to implement

should be something like:

```
ArrayList eventdetail = repond(url...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you need time to research. Seems like you have just started.

Their are lot of ways to do this.

You can use Rest API's or SOAP API's whichever you feel like.
or You can build your own http client on android to request and recieve data from web server.

all the best.

For SOAP you can use [Ksoap2](https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android)

For implementing Volley this is the [best source](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html).

Comment: thanks for your respond. I can used volley to get a string requested. I'm looking for and library or api that can use less line of code. Some thing like ArrayList A = getRespond(URL) . Which method do u recommend?

Comment: For that volley is fine. It handle everything. You just have to make response and then pass it to queue. If you haven't used volley yet. official android developer page is best to start from.

Comment: thanks can help me I put my detail problem under this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991227/json-array-return-blank-when-run-oncreate-android/33993300#33993300

Answer (score 0):

use below code to parse json array

```
               JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                JSONArray jArrayVersion = json.getJSONArray("result");

                for (int j = 0; j < jArrayVersion.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject items = jArrayVersion.getJSONObject(j);

                    String namesv = items.getString("name");
                    String message = items.getString("message");

                   }
```

//JSONParser class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

    public class JSONParser {

        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {

        }

        public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                System.out.println("url " + url);
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
                 int timeoutSocket = 6000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                System.out.println("url " + url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                System.out.println("url0 " + url);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                System.out.println("url1 " + url);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                System.out.println("url2 " + url);
                is = httpEntity.getContent();           

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your guide. I though make http request is old method. Now we have volley and some other better method?