# Json Array return blank ("") when run Oncreate (android)

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, android-volley

I am trying to fetch json data from server using volley library and store in array list then display data using spinner.

my code on php server side:

```
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
```

My fetch data function:

```
private void getEventRespondTest (RequestQueue requestQueue) {
        //Creating a string request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,Config.DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject respond) {
                            try {
                                eventArray = respond.getJSONArray("result");
                                Toast.makeText(Beacon_MainActivity.this,eventArray.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                eventDetail = getEventDetail(eventArray);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
//                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(Beacon_MainActivity.this, "Unable to fetch data: " +error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                );
        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    private ArrayList getEventDetail(JSONArray j) {
        ArrayList event = new ArrayList();
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding the name of the event to array list
                event.add(json.getString(Config.EVENT_TITLE));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(Beacon_MainActivity.this,event.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return event;
    }
```

And on my `OnCreate` method I am trying to fetch the data and display result using spinner but when run, result return first time is blank "

```
eventDetail = new ArrayList<>();
        eventArray = new JSONArray();

//        //get event from server
        getEventRespondTest(Volley.newRequestQueue(Beacon_MainActivity.this));
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(Beacon_MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, eventDetail));
```

Any help is much appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that the json is not null?

Comment: hi this is my Json URL: http://vinhvumobile.com/phpconnect/geteventdetail.php     I paste it on browser and get Json result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `private void getEventRespondTest` is returning null as it is `Void`. What are you doing `with eventDetail = getEventDetail(eventArray);` `getEventRespondTest`  function? Or tried to change POST to GET?

**UPDATE CHECK THIS CODE**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getEventRespondTest();
    }


 private void getEventRespondTest () {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest("http://vinhvumobile.com/phpconnect/geteventdetail.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // we got the response, now our job is to handle it
                getDataFromJson(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //something happened, treat the error.
                Log.e("Error", error.toString());
            }
        });
        queue.add(request);
    }

    private ArrayList getDataFromJson(String json) {
        ArrayList events=new ArrayList();
        JSONArray array;
        try {

            JSONObject gallery=new JSONObject(json);
            array=gallery.getJSONArray("result");
            //Do sth with it

            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonOBJ = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                events.add(jsonOBJ.get("EventID"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return events;
    }
```

Comment: my getEventRespondTest function is to fetch the respond from server and store into eventDetail  ArrayList. I supposed after calling getEventRespondTest. The eventDetail ArrayList will be updated with the data fetch from server and then i 'll display them using my spinner

Comment: put breakpoint into onResponse method and check log for errors. IS your getEventRespondTest declared in Fragment/Activity or in some other class?

Comment: how to put break point into onRespond? I have just checked the getEventRespondTest only decare in OnCreate method

Comment: Put on variable/array inside it. I assume that you are using android studio?

Comment: I still can not get your ideal. here is my Oncreate method code and function. Can help me take a look? https://docs.google.com/document/d/16APWQippnSNr0_BWqDQd36kzRA6IpbsLSHKIt0xgEFY/edit (from page 2, page 1 is php server side)

Comment: I'm using android studio 1.5

Comment: what is the different between POST and GET? I mainly use POST

Comment: Check new edited answer. Copy and try. I hope it helps.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 MEthod definitions : [HTTP_Methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Comment: thanks a lot. I will test with the code. So we change respond from JsonObjectRequest to StringRequest?

Comment: I have tested it in android studio and it work. Please check this as answer.

Comment: can u load your project test sample some where. I try but this method getDataFromJson(response); return ArrayList but we haven't assign the value to any variable.                                                                                      public void onResponse(String response) {
                // we got the response, now our job is to handle it
                getDataFromJson(response);

Comment: Here you go just unzip it:  [Test1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2o7elkz1hst2n5x/Test1.rar?dl=0)

Comment: Hi I run through your code but can not see where you the Result ArrayList into any variable?

Comment: getDataFromJson returns string array. You can use eventDetail=getDataFromJson(response) to populate your global variable in class.

Comment: Hi i  tried to assign the same and make a Toast to display evendetail arraylist but still have blank "". Can test again?

Answer (score 0):

I think you response in method  `public void onResponse(JSONObject respond)`   `respond  is null` because you use `JsonObjectRequest` to make request but your server(php) return a `String` it mean nothing `JsonObject` to return. Try use `StringRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest` . In best solution is change code your server for it return a `JsonObject' follow this (php file):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result), 256); // 256 for UTF-8 data
```

Comment: Can u explain in detail? This is my whole php file to fetch data from server <?php
 
 
>require_once('dbconnect.php');
 
$sql = "SELECT EventID, EventTitle, EventDesc, EventTime FROM Event";
 
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 
$result = array();

 
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
  array_push($result,array(
   'EventID'=>$row['EventID'],
      'EventTitle'=>$row['EventTitle'],
      'EventDesc'=>$row['EventDesc'],
      'EventTime'=>$row['EventTime']
  ));
 }
 
 echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
 
 mysqli_close($con);
 
 
?>

Comment: Can u explain in detail? this is my whole php file to fetch data. Can help me take a look? https://docs.google.com/document/d/16APWQippnSNr0_BWqDQd36kzRA6IpbsLSHKIt0xgEFY/edit

Comment: `<?php
 
 
require_once('dbconnect.php');
 
$sql = "SELECT EventID, EventTitle, EventDesc, EventTime FROM Event";
 
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 
$result = array();

 
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,array(
            'EventID'=>$row['EventID'],
            'EventTitle'=>$row['EventTitle'],
            'EventDesc'=>$row['EventDesc'],
            'EventTime'=>$row['EventTime']
        ));
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result), 256);
    
    
 
 
?>`